# Javascript - Sorting HTML Table (with column that has data and time)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table that sorts ascending/descending when i click the column name, I follow the examples in w3schools

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp

But this is not sort the date that has time right (6/1/2019 8:15:00 AM)

Do you have any other suggestions or code to add on the sample of w3schools.

Comment: Please include all code relevant to the question in the question itself. Please give an example of what you have and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The W3Schools example compares two strings. Thus, it compares the two dates alphabetically, not temporally.

```
if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase())
```

You need to convert the value to a Date and compare the date values.

Relevant portion:

```
x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];

var date1 = new Date(x.innerText);
var date2 = new Date(y.innerText);

if (date1 > date2) {
```

Working example (based on [W3School's code](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sort_table)):

```html
<style>
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 16px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}
</style>

<p>Click the button to sort the table alphabetically, by name:</p>
<p><button onclick="sortTable()">Sort</button></p>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6/1/2019 8:15:00 AM</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6/1/2019 6:15:00 AM</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6/1/2019 3:15:30 AM</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6/1/2019 8:15:00 AM</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6/1/2019 8:15:00 PM</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6/1/2019 8:15:00 AM</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6/1/2019 4:15:00 PM</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6/2/2019 8:15:30 PM</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
function sortTable() {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
      
      var date1 = new Date(x.innerText);
      var date2 = new Date(y.innerText);
      //check if the two rows should switch place:
      if (date1 > date2) {
        //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```